# A responsive SVG shape with parallax image not full width

Tags: html, css, mask

I am having some issues with getting my SVG shape full width of the viewport, so it will work responsive for all devices.

I tried already some things like `clip-path: view-box;` but with no results. The main property that makes the SVG shape not responsive is the `clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`, but since I would like to have a images with parallax inside the SVG shape I looking for a way that it will also work with the clipPath property.

What am I currently overlooking, or what is the best way to achieve this. If there are any other suggestions to use a SVG as image mask, please let me know.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 896">
    <clipPath id="my-clip-path" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect y="149.3" width="329" height="298.7" fill="red" />
      <rect y="597.3" width="329" height="298.7" fill="red"/>
      <path
            d="M1440,149.3V896H478.3V597.3h866.1c16.5,0,29.9-13.4,29.9-29.9v-89.6c0-16.5-13.4-29.9-29.9-29.9H478.3V0h448v149.3H1440z" />
    </clipPath>
  </svg>
  <div class="clipped">
    <img class="image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595987357195-9d86aeba0fa2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=4000&q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
svg {
  // width: 200px;
  clip-path: view-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clipped {
  width: 100%; // was 500px
  height: 100%; // was 800px
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
  clip-path: url(#my-clip-path);
}

.image {
  width: 150%;
}
```

Live codepen: https://codepen.io/Caspert/pen/jOJxpZp

Comment: Your SVG image looks weird, it's not symmetrical. Check it first without clipping to be sure the shape is correct.

Comment: The shape is correct. It's a style element ;)

Comment: You haven't described precisely in what way it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, one option is to use `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` on the `clipPath`, when you do that, the clip path will be relative to the image. Then you need to convert the svg children values to relative values in the range of `0-1`. As far as I know, there isn't a tool to easily convert those values, so you can basically calculate by dividing the absolute values by its maximum width/height, e.g. `329 / 1440` for rect width.

[Here is the forked codepen](https://codepen.io/damzaky/pen/dyrwavY)